# Greedy graph coloring using networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have attached my code below. I created a complete graph and tried to use greedy_color() function so that no nodes next to each other are assigned the same color. But the problem is, greedy_color() function is returning number same as the node (Not using least colors possible). How can I solve this?

```
 import networkx as nx
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import itertools

 net = nx.complete_graph(20)
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
 #nx.draw(net)

 d = nx.coloring.greedy_color(net)
 print(d)

 OUTPUT:


{
0: 0,
1: 1,
2: 2,
3: 3,
4: 4,
5: 5,
6: 6,
7: 7,
8: 8,
9: 9,
10: 10,
11: 11,
12: 12,
13: 13,
14: 14,
15: 15,
16: 16,
17: 17,
18: 18,
19: 19
}
```

I tried passing the graph created as a parameter inside greedy_color() But the output should give me a dictionary with value elements being repetitive and as least as possible for the given number of keys. (Key denotes nodes and value denotes color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, however complete graph means every node is next to each other, so each node will have a unique colour.

For example, modifying the graph to a different one gives the following:

```py
from networkx import greedy_color
from networkx import karate_club_graph

G = karate_club_graph()
print(greedy_color(G))
# {33: 0, 0: 0, 32: 1, 2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 3, 31: 2, 8: 3, 13: 4, 23: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 4, 27: 1, 29: 3, 30: 2, 4: 1, 10: 2, 19: 2, 24: 0, 25: 1, 28: 1, 9: 1, 12: 1, 14: 2, 15: 2, 16: 0, 17: 2, 18: 2, 20: 2, 21: 2, 22: 2, 26: 1, 11: 1}
```

Comment: Thank you, What should I do if I need to create a graph which has custom placed nodes and use greedy_color()? And also draw the nodes with different colors using nx.draw()

Comment: That's a separate question. :)